# How to handle horizontal and vertical scrolling at the same time within a webpage

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navigationbar, vertical-scrolling

I'm currently stumbling on a bit of a problem involving (smooth)scrolling and trying to "update" a navigation bar at the same time.

Currently I have a large webpage that has a lot of content under different headers. These headers are displayed in a navigation bar that spans the whole view width of the page, each of these elements are href's to smoothly scroll to the current position of the header.

The header the user is currently is viewing gets highlighted within the navigation bar. However I would also like to scroll this header to the front or middle of the navigation bar for easily navigating the page.

Using the following code:
`nav_bar.scrollBy(scrollAmount-125,0);`

All of this works completely fine until I introduce: `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` to the CSS. As soon as I call the `.scrollBy()` the smooth scrolling get interupted and halted before it can complete the scrolling to the element referenced by the href.

Is there any solution to fixing this problem, I tried to get the `.scrollBy()` to run after the scrolling is complete but have not been able to get this to fully function. The problem is with the `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` since removing this property gives the desired results for functionality but without my desired User Experience.

Comment: I have allready made this kind of stuff, and I din't have this problem... what have you done really ?

Comment: @MisterJojo im calling ```nav_bar.scrollBy(scrollAmount-500,0);``` within ```window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {}```